Blazor jsInterop addeventlistener for online works but not for offline
I have this js interop:
window.interop = {   
    registerOnline: function (instance) {
        window.addEventListener('online', (e) => {
            instance.invokeMethodAsync('CallSync');
        });              
    },
    registerOffline: function (instance) {
        window.addEventListener('offline', (e) => {
            instance.invokeMethodAsync('Offline');
        });
    },
    initialOnlineStatus: function () {
        return navigator.onLine;
    }
};

and this is the c# part:
public async Task Register()
 {
     var obj = DotNetObjectReference.Create(this);           
     await js.InvokeVoidAsync("interop.registerOnline", obj);
     await js.InvokeVoidAsync("interop.registerOffline", obj);
     IsOnline = await js.InvokeAsync<bool>("interop.initialOnlineStatus");            
}

when I turn on wifi and wait, the online status works, but if I turn off computers wifi, the offline doesn't work.
How to make offline event work?
